# AppServiceConnectionStatus returns AppNotInstalled when WinForm attempts to connect to UWP

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

I have been developing a UWP app for the past few weekends now. The UWP app relies on a Win32 (WinForms) Component to display `NotifyIcons` in the system tray. As a result of the nature of the app, I need two-way communication between the UWP and WinForms components. Both of which are programmed in C#. Sorry if I've missed some or other guide deep in the internet, but I've been struggling for a long time now.

The way I started was by creating a new solution with a UWP Project in, then, later on, I made the WinForms project. (no desktop bridging or whatever, everything is brand new)

My appropriate `package.appxmanifest` content:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
   </Capabilities>
   <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="Check Locked Keys (Free).exe" 
        EntryPoint="Check_Locked_Keys__Free_.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="Check Locked Keys (Free)" 
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" 
         Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="Check Locked 
          Keys (Free)" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
          <uap:AppService Name="CheckLockedKeysFreeService" />
        </uap:Extension>
        <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Win32\NotifyIconsComponent.exe" />
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
```

The code in the WinForms Component:

```
    public static AppServiceConnection connection;
    static AutoResetEvent appServiceExit;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Mutex mutex = null;
        if (!Mutex.TryOpenExisting("NotifyIconsLogicMutex", out mutex))
        {
            mutex = new Mutex(false, "NotifyIconsLogicMutex");
            InitAppServiceConnection();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new NotifyIconsLogic());
            mutex.Close();
        }
    }

    static async void InitAppServiceConnection()
    {
        NotifyIconsLogic notifyIconsLogic = new NotifyIconsLogic();
        connection = new AppServiceConnection();
        connection.PackageFamilyName = "859e8059-e2b6-4ce1-df076201303e_q0ycx5bathybm"; 
        connection.AppServiceName = "CheckLockedKeysFreeService";
        connection.RequestReceived += notifyIconsLogic.OnRequestReceived;
        connection.ServiceClosed += Connection_ServiceClosed;
        AppServiceConnectionStatus connectionStatus = await connection.OpenAsync();

        MessageBox.Show(connectionStatus.ToString());
    }

    private static void Connection_ServiceClosed(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceClosedEventArgs args)
    {
        // exit app
        appServiceExit.Set();
    }
```

Now, it compiles fine, but it just pops up a message box saying AppNotInstalled.??

If any more code snippets are needed, Please Let Me Know.

Also, when I run the UWP app (which automatically launches the Win32 Component) how do I debug the Win32 Component? I've tried to attach another instance of Visual Studio to it, but it just gives me an error saying that there is already a debugger attached to it.

Please Note that I have lots of experience working on the WinForms platform, but not so much on the UWP side of things.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Thank You

Dilan

Comment: Did you double-check that the hard-coded PackageFamily name is correct? Btw, you can also just use Package.Current.Id.FamilyName, to get the package family name without hardcodes.

Comment: Hi, sorry for only answering now. I've changed it to `Package.Current.Id.FamilyName` and it now returns `Success`, however the Win32 component still stops responding after a few seconds. How can I debug this?

Comment: Please open a new question about debugging a mixed UWP/Win32 project and mark this one answered, so we can check it off the list. Thx!

Comment: Hi, would you mind taking a look at the new question here: social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ee15254-1b94-4f75-8818-b01fa5f775f3/debug-win32-component-functioning-as-appservice-in-uwp-app?forum=csharpgeneral ? Sorry, stackoverflow is being picky...

Comment: I have responded on the MSDN forum

Comment: I added the code to send in UWP and to receive in the SystemTray but for some reason, the UWP app is sending to itself 
I am not sure if i should create a new service or add any custom configuration to the app.config of the winforms. Any documentation or suggestion will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Package.Current.Id.FamilyName, to get the package family name and avoid using hardcoded family names.